# How to refresh or extend a google access token passed by Android App without refresh token in server?

Tags: android, google-api, access-token, google-authentication, google-api-java-client

I am building a worker server using a google api client for access a youtube api.

Firstly, An android are using the Google SDK that have  "GoogleAuthUtil.getToken" doesn't make refresh token. and pass a access token to worker server to access api.

Secondly, A Server are using the "google api services" client with the access token for a while.

Since doesn't get a refresh token from a android, a access token doesn't be refreshed although it's expired.

Have any possible way to refresh in server? or does android pass a new access token every a hour?

Comment: You should not be pasing around an access token this is a security risk.  Your android login should go though the java client and the java client should be using a hybrid login which will return it a refresh token.

Comment: @DaImTo I understand what you say. Decided to pass an access token from an App. It is quite easy to think, just I was confused about a token policy. Thanks!